# How can I modify this query to get just username and password and send to next page?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am not good with jQuery. However, I have a form that needs to be validated in a certain format.

Please see screenshot to see how the form should look like when a user attempts a submit without providing values for username/password.

[image]

I searched around for jQuery script that meets our spec and found the script below.

How do I modify it to have just username and password and as soon as user fills the form with those values and clicks the Submit button, s/he is taken page2.aspx?

So far, when I fill the form and click the submit button, I get an alert:

```
submit! use link below to go to the other step
```

At the very least, can I just change this alert to redirect so it takes me to page2.aspx?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.mockjax({
        url: "emails.action",
        response: function(settings) {
            var email = settings.data.email,
                emails = ["glen@marketo.com", "george@bush.gov", "me@god.com", "aboutface@cooper.com", "steam@valve.com", "bill@gates.com"];
            this.responseText = "true";
            if ( $.inArray( email, emails ) !== -1 ) {
                this.responseText = "false";
            }
        },
        responseTime: 500
    });

    jQuery.validator.addMethod("password", function( value, element ) {
        var result = this.optional(element) || value.length >= 6 && /\d/.test(value) && /[a-z]/i.test(value);
        if (!result) {
            element.value = "";
            var validator = this;
            setTimeout(function() {
                validator.blockFocusCleanup = true;
                element.focus();
                validator.blockFocusCleanup = false;
            }, 1);
        }
        return result;
    }, "Your password must be at least 6 characters long and contain at least one number and one character.");

    // a custom method making the default value for companyurl ("http://") invalid, without displaying the "invalid url" message
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("defaultInvalid", function(value, element) {
        return value != element.defaultValue;
    }, "");

    jQuery.validator.addMethod("billingRequired", function(value, element) {
        if ($("#bill_to_co").is(":checked"))
            return $(element).parents(".subTable").length;
        return !this.optional(element);
    }, "");

    jQuery.validator.messages.required = "";
    $("form").validate({
        invalidHandler: function(e, validator) {
            var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
            if (errors) {
                var message = errors == 1
                    ? 'You missed 1 field. It has been highlighted above'
                    : 'You missed ' + errors + ' fields.  They have been highlighted above';
                $("div.error span").html(message);
                $("div.error").show();
            } else {
                $("div.error").hide();
            }
        },
        onkeyup: false,
        submitHandler: function() {
            $("div.error").hide();
            alert("submit! use link below to go to the other step");
        },
        messages: {
            password2: {
                required: " ",
                equalTo: "Please enter the same password as above"
            },
            email: {
                required: " ",
                email: "Please enter a valid email address, example: you@yourdomain.com",
                remote: jQuery.validator.format("{0} is already taken, please enter a different address.")
            }
        },
        debug:true
    });

  $(".resize").vjustify();
  $("div.buttonSubmit").hoverClass("buttonSubmitHover");

  $("input.phone").mask("(999) 999-9999");
  $("input.zipcode").mask("99999");
  var creditcard = $("#creditcard").mask("9999 9999 9999 9999");

  $("#cc_type").change(
    function() {
      switch ($(this).val()){
        case 'amex':
          creditcard.unmask().mask("9999 999999 99999");
          break;
        default:
          creditcard.unmask().mask("9999 9999 9999 9999");
          break;
      }
    }
  );

  // toggle optional billing address
  var subTableDiv = $("div.subTableDiv");
  var toggleCheck = $("input.toggleCheck");
  toggleCheck.is(":checked")
    ? subTableDiv.hide()
    : subTableDiv.show();
  $("input.toggleCheck").click(function() {
      if (this.checked == true) {
        subTableDiv.slideUp("medium");
        $("form").valid();
      } else {
        subTableDiv.slideDown("medium");
      }
  });


});

$.fn.vjustify = function() {
    var maxHeight=0;
    $(".resize").css("height","auto");
    this.each(function(){
        if (this.offsetHeight > maxHeight) {
          maxHeight = this.offsetHeight;
        }
    });
    this.each(function(){
        $(this).height(maxHeight);
        if (this.offsetHeight > maxHeight) {
            $(this).height((maxHeight-(this.offsetHeight-maxHeight)));
        }
    });
};

$.fn.hoverClass = function(classname) {
    return this.hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass(classname);
    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass(classname);
    });
};
```

This is the link below where I got the script. If you click on the Finish button, you see the behavior we are looking to mimick.

http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/marketo/step2.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need all of that. Keep in mind that all validation should also be done server side. If you need to check the database for username and password, you need to include an ajax call.

```
<div class="loginStatus"></div>
<div class="alert"></div>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
<input type="text" name="password" id="password" />
<button id="submitButton">Submit</button>
```

End html

```
 $(function() {
   $('#submitButton').on('click', function() {
     var username = $('#username').val();
     var password = $('#password').val();
     if(username.length < 6) {
       $('#username').css('border', '1px solid red');
       $('.alert').html('Please enter valid username');
       $('.loginStatus').html('Bad');
       return false;
     }
     if(password.length < 6) {
       $('#password').css('border', '1px solid red');
       $('.alert').html('Please enter valid password');
       $('.loginStatus').html('Bad');
       return false;
     }
     $('.loginStatus').html('good');
     $('#username').css('border', '1px solid #3c3c3c');
     $('#password').css('border', '1px solid #3c3c3c');
     $.ajax({
      url: "checklogin.aspx?un="+ username + '&pw=' + password, //send values to server side code to check if they are valid in database
      cache: false
     })
     .done(function( html ){ //send back response
        $('.loginStatus').html(html); //sends whether login status is valid
        if($('.loginStatus').text() === 'good') { //this is some hidden container that holds a value of good or bad
           window.location = "page2.aspx"; //if login is good then advance to next page
      }
    }) 
   });
 });
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time.

I did run your code and three issues.

One, we are not validating for password length although that's a minor problem I can resolve.

Two, when I enter username and hit the ENTER key, it goes straight to page2.aspx. The check for password doesn't work.

Three, they don't want alert. They want similar message as the one I posted earlier.

Please see link I just posted above. That's where I got the code.

Comment: tested this and it works. I didnt test the last code. the alert appears at the top now. I hard coded the containers at the top, however they should be sent by the aspx page. You need to create the aspx page and have it send back good if the user exists within the database.